# Populate added_by field from CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have extended [django-taggit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) `TagBase` model to include an `added_by` field as a ForeignKey to `User`:

```
class TagBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), unique=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_("Slug"), unique=True, max_length=100)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Everything works great, however I'm having an issue with populating that field from my CreateView. This is what I have tried:

```
class NoteCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Note
    fields = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'notebook',
        'tags'
    ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.added_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.save()
        for tag in form.instance.tags.all():
            tag.added_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
IntegrityError at /notes/1/create/ NOT NULL constraint failed: taggit_tag.added_by_id
```

How do I properly autopopulate `added_by` field on my tag instances?

Answer (score 0):

Is the user anonymous? I think you can **print** the **self.request.user** to check.